# How to compile a C# programm in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How i can make something like a "builder" for my application. Let me explain it in a example:

application.exe

```
System.Console;

private class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {    
        WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Now i want to have another C# program that is able to compile this program but change the string message to what the user desires.

i hope you can understand what i mean with my bad English and bad explanation skills.

Comment: Uh, do you need to re-compile the program to do that...? I think you don't need to..

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to give the "string message the user desires" as an **argument** to that programming, to let it dynamically react on it? Editing the sourcecode and letting it recompile is a bad approach for it.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail? Sorry im a Beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length >0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0].ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Complile the Program and execute it using cmd prompt with any string you want as parameter.